# Структура функции ООП

Tags: php, ооп, fluent-interface

```
DB::table('users')->select('name','surname')->where('id', $userId)->get();
```

Какова структура класса в данном коде?

Получается вызывается статический метод `table` класса `DB`, а `select`,`where` это что, переменные класса? А `get()` функция в функции?

Comment: `table` возвращает объект, потом `select` на этом объекте возвращает объект, потом `where`, в конце у объекта, который вернул `where`, вызывается метод `get`.

Comment: если Вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, [отметьте ответ решением](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), чтобы он не висел в открытых.

Answer (score 3):

Последовательное выполнение методов класса `DB`:

1. `DB::table('users')` - выполняется метод `table`, вернет экземпляр класса `DB` для построения запроса к базе данных, связанный с таблицей `users`;
2. `->select('name','surname')` - выполняется метод `select` с аргументами переменной длины;
3. `->where('id', $userId)` - выполняется метод `where` с аргументами переменной длины;
4. `->get()` - выполняется метод `get` который формирует запрос и получает результаты.

В пунктах 1, 2, 3 возвращается экземпляр класса `DB` (`object()`) для построения запроса к БД, вероятнее всего при выполнении этих методов происходит присвоение переменным класса `DB` соответствующих значений для запроса, которые потом используются для построения запроса при выполнении `->get()`.

---

**UPD** - полезные ссылки

Как верно [отметил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/737267/#comment1124103_737272) [@Deonis](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/4058/) подобная реализация называется "*Текучий интерфейс (fluent interface)*".

Полезные ссылки с примерами и описанием:

1. Википедия - [«Fluent interface»](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface)
2. Хабрахабр - [Шаблон программирования «Текучий интерфейс» в PHP](https://habrahabr.ru/post/170019/)
3. Хабрахабр - [«Расширенный текучий интерфейс»](https://habrahabr.ru/post/132115/)
4. Хабрахабр - [«Шаблоны проектирования с человеческим лицом»](https://habrahabr.ru/company/mailru/blog/325492/)

Comment: Можно дополнить, что такая реализация называется "fluent interface" (текучий интерфейс)

Comment: Я бы дополнил, сказав что там паттерн строитель еще намешан. А так Структура такая: В классе DB есть все эти методы плюс один метод get (), который все что перед ним подсовывает в класс который заточен на выборку из базы
https://habrahabr.ru/company/mailru/blog/325492/#imagehttpshabrastorageorgfiles301beff6b301beff6b71b4be18c4ab10aaabb464fpng-stroitel